# Perl regex to extract digits from string with parenthesis

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following string:

```
my $string = "Ethernet FlexNIC (NIC 1) LOM1:1-a    FC:15:B4:13:6A:A8";
```

I want to extract the number that is in brackets (1) in another variable.
The following statement does not work:

```
my ($NAdapter) = $string =~ /\((\d+)\)/;
```

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: escape brackets like `\((\d+)\)` and get the first matched group.

Comment: @Braj: That's what he did. It doesn't work because he doesn't have any sets of brackets that only contain digits.

Answer (score 3):

```
\d+(?=[^(]*\))
```

You can use this.See demo.Yours will not work as inside `()` there is more data besides `\d+`.

https://regex101.com/r/fM9lY3/57

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like

```
my ($NAdapter) = $string =~ /\(.*(\d+).*\)/;
```

After that, `$NAdapter` should include the number that you want.

Comment: @vks Yes, my solution only a little more general than what the poster needs, not the most general one.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> my $string = "Ethernet FlexNIC (NIC 1) LOM1:1-a    FC:15:B4:13:6A:A8";
> ```
>
> I want to extract the number that is in brackets (1) in another
>   variable

Your regex (with some spaces for clarity):

```
/ \( (\d+) \) /x;
```

says to match:

1. A literal opening parenthesis, immediately followed by...
2. A digit, one or more times (captured in group 1), immediately followed by...
3. A literal closing parenthesis.

Yet, the substring you want to match:

```
(NIC 1)
```

is of the form:

1. A literal opening parenthesis, immediately followed by...
2. Some capital letters 
   STOP EVERYTHING! NO MATCH!

As an alternative, your substring:

```
(NIC 1)
```

could be described as:

1. Some digits, immediately followed by...
2. A literal closing parenthesis.

Here's the regex:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.020;

my $string = "Ethernet FlexNIC (NIC 1234) LOM1:1-a    FC:15:B4:13:6A:A8";

my ($match) = $string =~ /
    (\d+)   #Match any digit, one or more times, captured in group 1, followed by...

    \)      #a literal closing parenthesis. 
            #Parentheses have a special meaning in a regex--they create a capture
            #group--so if you want to match a parenthesis in your string, you
            #have to escape the parenthesis in your regex with a backslash.

/xms;  #Standard flags that some people apply to every regex.

say $match;

--output:--
1234
```

Another description of your substring:

```
(NIC 1)
```

could be:

1. A literal opening parenthesis, immediately followed by...
2. Some non-digits, immediately followed by...
3. Some digits, immediately followed by..
4. A literal closing parenthesis.

Here's the regex:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.020;

my $string = "Ethernet FlexNIC (ABC NIC789) LOM1:1-a    FC:15:B4:13:6A:A8";

my ($match) = $string =~ /

    \(      #Match a literal opening parethesis, followed by...
    \D+     #a non-digit, one or more times, followed by...
    (\d+)   #a digit, one or more times, captured in group 1, followed by...
    \)      #a literal closing parentheses.

/xms;  #Standard flags that some people apply to every regex.

say $match;

--output:--
789
```

If there might be spaces on some lines and not others, such as:

```
    spaces
      || 
      VV
(NIC 1  )
(NIC 2)
```

You can insert a `\s*` (any whitespace, zero or more times) in the appropriate place in the regex, for instance:

```
my ($match) = $string =~ /
            #Parentheses have special meaning in a regex--they create a capture
            #group--so if you want to match a parenthesis in your string, you
            #have to escape the parenthesis in your regex with a backslash.
    \(      #Match a literal opening parethesis, followed by...

    \D+     #a non-digit, one or more times, followed by...
    (\d+)   #a digit, one or more times, captured in group 1, followed by...
    \s*     #any whitespace, zero or more times, followed by...
    \)      #a literal closing parentheses.

/xms;  #Standard flags that some people apply to every regex.
```